# Why can I console.log() the html of a node, but MutationObserver fails to recognise it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

Im trying to use MutationObserver on a `<div>` but am getting the error:

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on
> 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

indicating the MutationObserver cannot find the node or is loading before the node appears (which is strange as the div is just a normal part of the DOM - not added dynamically).

However if I do:

```
console.log($("#myDiv").html());
```

before my MutationObserver script it returns the divs html, as expected.

I'm curious as to why this is?

My full code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log($("#myDiv").html());
    const container = $("#myDiv");
    const options = { childList: true };
    
    const observer = new MutationObserver(function onMutation(mutations, observer) {
      console.log('Mutations', mutations)
    });
    
    observer.observe(container, options);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MutationObserver` is a native javascript feature, so won't understand jquery objects.

Changing

```
const container = $("#myDiv");
```

to

```
const container = $("#myDiv")[0];
```

or using `observer.observe(container[0], options);`

will convert the jquery object to the native javascript node which can then be used by the MutationObserver.